grand total for calculated field in tableau
Our current Tableau dashboard calculates individual employee rewards correctly using the [Listing Reward Final] calculated field.
CASE attr([Calendar WeekInPeriod])
WHEN 4 THEN
    CASE sum([Listing Flag])
        WHEN 8 THEN 20 WHEN 9 THEN 25 WHEN 10 THEN 35 WHEN 11 THEN 50
        WHEN 12 THEN 70 WHEN 13 THEN 95 WHEN 14 THEN 125 WHEN 15 THEN 160
        WHEN 16 THEN 200 ELSE
            IF sum([Listing Flag]) < 8 THEN 0
            ELSE 200 + (sum([Listing Flag]) - 16) * 50
            END
    END
WHEN 3 THEN
    CASE sum([Listing Flag])
        WHEN 6 THEN 20 WHEN 7 THEN 25 WHEN 8 THEN 35 WHEN 9 THEN 50
        WHEN 10 THEN 70 WHEN 11 THEN 95 WHEN 12 THEN 125 WHEN 13 THEN 160
        WHEN 14 THEN 200 ELSE
            IF sum([Listing Flag]) < 6 THEN 0
            ELSE 200 + (sum([Listing Flag]) - 14) * 50
            END
    END
WHEN 5 THEN
    CASE sum([Listing Flag])
        WHEN 10 THEN 20 WHEN 11 THEN 25 WHEN 12 THEN 35 WHEN 13 THEN 50
        WHEN 14 THEN 70 WHEN 15 THEN 95 WHEN 16 THEN 125 WHEN 17 THEN 160
        WHEN 18 THEN 200 ELSE
            IF sum([Listing Flag]) < 10 THEN 0
            ELSE 200 + (sum([Listing Flag]) - 18) * 50
            END
    END
ELSE NULL
END

However, the grand total is incorrectly applying the reward formula to the sum of all listing flags, resulting in an inflated total of 5,500 instead of the correct sum of 905.
Current Behavior:

Individual employee rewards are calculated correctly.
Grand total applies the reward formula to the sum of all listing flags (122), resulting in 5,500.

Desired Behavior:

Individual employee rewards remain the same.
Grand total should be the sum of individual employee rewards (905).




Grand Total
Listing Flag
5,500




Emp 1
11
50


Emp 2
17
250


Emp 3
12
70


Emp 4
7
0


Emp 5
8
20


Emp 6
13
95


Emp 7
3
0


Emp 8
12
70


Emp 9
18
300


Emp 10
4
0


Emp 11
6
0


Emp 12




Emp 13
11
50


Emp 14






If you are using the grand total from the Analysis tab at the top, it adds everything in the pane, if you want, you can create another calc field and have it [FIXED] to your employee level.
